# Creating my own tracking analytics for my android app

Tags: android, sqlite, google-analytics, mobile-application

I used to use Google Analytics for tracking of my application's different features on my users device but since I need to get more information, I'd rather create this analytics on my own so that I can have many other features like how often my users are using the app and other stuff.

The solution I have in my mind is to add a **jar** file to my application where it retreives the data whenever user is using the app and stores the in the SQLite database of phone and when user is connected to the internet, the data are sent to my webservices on my server-side.
I need to know have a feedback, that what drawbacks this method has. Does it affect the quality of the app in terms of its speed etc ?

Anyone has any other suggestions for solving this issue?

Comment: You know countly? http://count.ly

Comment: I've heard of that.. But it doesnt give me the functionalities that I'm lookin for